# Augury isn't work properly "Cannot read property '1' of null"

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, augury

Augury isn't work properly "Cannot read property '1' of null" . 
When i try to connect to augury devtool to see my tree elements error show up, how can I fix it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

I don't know what do you need to this so i share my package.json

```
{
  "name": "protein-nutrition",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.9",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^9.1.2",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^9.1.2",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^9.1.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "^9.1.2",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^9.1.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.9",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

If need to add more library just say inside comment.
Thank you a lot!!

Comment: So your app works properly, the error is just when using Augury?

Comment: yes , when I am using Augury and click there this problems start to show

Comment: please help guys , i don't find any solution.

Comment: no one know solution

Answer (score 0):

Seems Augury is not compatible with Angular 9 (Ivy) :

> Augury currently does not have support for Angular Ivy as of Augury v1
> (https://github.com/rangle/augury#supported-version)

I tried to [enable debug for AOT](https://github.com/rangle/augury#support-for-aot-ahead-of-time-compilation), but still fails:

```json
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "debug": true
}
```

I even tried the "Components only" config.

https://github.com/rangle/augury/issues/1455

Sadly, I think it's time to switch to another tool: https://github.com/rangle/augury/issues/1483